# Multiple Choice on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm taking the plunge into my first iOS app (for fun), and have decided to make myself a flash-cards type app to study with. Basically, show a picture and under it have a few selections to choose from, with one being the right answer. This is the basic functionality that I would like to have.

I've been through the iOS videos and a few open courseware courses and I'm ready to start but I'm absolutely drawing a blank as to where to begin.. Anyone have an idea for such a beginner as me? :)

Answer (score 0):

A very vague question. But then a simple start to solving this would be to use a UIImageView for the picture and a UITableView/UIPickerView below for the options.

Read up more on the mechanisms of the tableview/pickerview delegate methods. Read those class references on Apple's documention: UITableView [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and UIPickerView [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).

Also read up on data structures like [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to understand how to use them when you deal with populating data into your table or picker and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UIImageView as the picture and use either a UITableView, UIPickerView, or UIButtons for the answer choices. Then, just have your answer choices randomly gather answers from a SQLite database, otherwise your users could memorize the quiz!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this, is create a plist with an array of dictionaries. For each dictionary, have 4 keys:

```
1- Question (String) -> The question itself
2- Array (of NSStrings) - > list of options
3- Index (Number) of correct option
4- Image (String) -> Image name
```

So once you have bunch of these, create a UIViewController, put a UIImageView in it, a UILabel, and a UITableView.

Then do this repeatedly for each question you want to display:

Hook up UIImageView with UIImage (you can get the name of that image from the dictionary).Then, hook up the label with name of the question, and popualte the tableview with options. Then listen for UITableViewDidSelect call back, check if the answer is correct or not, and then reset the entire view controller with the next question.

Btw, you will need an array with keeps track of what choice the user made so at the end of the quiz you can come back and refer to it.

Hope that helps, it may sound complicated but it's pretty straightforward once you get your head around it.